# Can One GFCI Serve Several Outlets

Tags: electrical

The house was built in 1996 and one (1) service box breaker and one (1) GFCI located in one bathroom serves all three bathrooms including three (3) brick-mounted outdoor outlets. Can this single GFCI serve to pass inspection today or should I replace the three (3) outdoor outlets with GFCI's and appropriate box covers?

Comment: It is a 15-Amp circuit.

Answer (score 7):

Should be no problem. As long as the downstream receptacles are wired off the LOAD side of the GFCI, they are protected.

Comment: Are you allowed to have outdoor outlets chained off a bathroom circuit?

Comment: Um...  Technically, no. Current code requires a 20 ampere circuit to serve only the bathrooms. But I believe there was a point in time where it was acceptable and fairly common. It also might be allowed if this is a circuit in addition to the required bathroom circuit.  If it was installed like this before the code change, then it's fine. If you just wired it like that, you'll likely fail inspection.